# How to prove that $\{a\}=\{a',b'\} \Rightarrow a=a'=b' $?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I'm using Jean-Louis Krivine's book "Theorie des ensembles" as a reference book so the notations might be a little different from english literature, but i guess the question is easy to follow.

Let $\mathcal U$ be a universe (a collection of objects that is supposedly not empty, the objects are called sets). We define a binary relation on this universe that we note "$\in$".

**Axiom of extensionality:**  $\forall x \forall y[\forall z(z\in x\Leftrightarrow z \in y)\Rightarrow x=y]$.

**Axiom of pairing:** $\forall x \forall y \exists z\forall t[t\in z\Leftrightarrow (t=x \lor t=y)]$.

My question is, assuming only these two axioms, how to prove that if we had sets $a,a' and\ b'$ satisfying $\{a\}=\{a',b'\}$ then $ a=a'=b' $?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have that $a' \in \{ a',b′ \} = \{ a \}$ and $b' \in \{ a',b′ \} = \{ a \}$.

But $a' \in \{ a \}$ means that $a'=a$, and the same with $b'$.

Thus, from transitivity of *equality*:

> $a'=a=b'$.

Comment: My bad, i thought that $\{a\}=\{a′,b′\}$ means that $ a' \in a\,$ which is false, and instead we have $ a' \in \{a\}$, and $\{a\}$ being the only set containig $a$ and just $a$ gives $a'=a$.
thank you so much for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If you don't like the direct route you can go by contradiction: Suppose $a \neq a'$, for example. Then use pairing to obtain the sets $\{ a \}$ and $\{ a',b' \}$. Now use the contrapositive of extensionality; what do you get?